# How do I move/align the right box component closer to the left?

Tags: css, sass

There were recently 3 component boxes, but the middle one was not needed anymore, so I just deleted it.

Yet, when I deleted the middlebox(blue color), the 2 remaining boxes became too far apart and it doesn't make it look nice.

How do I move the far-right red box closer to the middle to align with the yellow box?

[image]

code

```
@import '../../scss/variables.scss';
.dashboard {
    &__module {
        padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
        flex-basis: 30%;
        flex-grow: 0;
        color: $white;

        &:nth-child(1) {
            background-color: $orange;
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
            background-color: $red;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
            background-color: $blue;
        }
        a {
            color: $white;
        }
    }
    &__module_header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid white;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        display: flex;
    }
    &__module_title {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex: 1 0;
    }
    &__module_title_link {
        justify-self: flex-end;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    &__module_row {
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    &__module_stat_container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        &.primary {
            font-size: 18px;
            .dashboard__module_stat {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }
    &__module_stat {
        width: 20px;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    &__module_date {
        width: 50px;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    &__module_subtext {
        font-size: 14px;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:920px){
    .dashboard__modules_container {
        display:block !important;
        width: 100%;

        .dashboard {
            &__module {
                padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                flex-basis: 100%;
                flex-grow: 0;
                color: $white;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

switch

justify-content: space-between;

to

justify-content: space-evenly;

[image]